# Which is the theme template file that contains the logo image of the site?

Tags: theming

I need to change the output of the logo (to make it adapative) of a site. Which is the theme template file that contains the logo image of the site?

Comment: Just want to change the logo ?

Comment: I need to add a 'image style' attribute to the image logo to make it adaptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$logo` variable is printed from `page.tpl.php` *around* line 77.

```
<?php if ($logo): ?>
  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Depending on what you want to do though you could also use [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).

Comment: my page.tpl.php page is different. I'm using a sub-theme of the omega theme. I need to add a 'image style' attribute to the image logo to make it adaptive. Can I do this with template_preprocess_page()?

Comment: If you want reponsive, just add `width:100%` to the logo `img` itself with CSS and it'll expand/contract to the width of the parent container.